# Facebook 'Like' Button is not appearing in footer

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a facebook 'like' button in the footer of my website, but after using the facebook developers configuration for it, it is not showing on the screen. I am using bootstrap framework.

The code I have copied from facebook developers is :

```
    <!-- *****************************************************************************************************************
 FOOTER
 ***************************************************************************************************************** -->
 <div id="footerwrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
               <div class="fb-like" 
                    data-href="mywebsitenamehere.com"  
                    data-width="300" 
                    data-height="50"
                    data-layout="button_count" 
                    data-action="like" 
                    data-show-faces="false" 
                    data-share="true">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">

            </div>

        </div><! --/row -->
    </div><! --/container -->
 </div><! --/footerwrap -->
```

And I also added the sdk just inside the body of the html:

```
    <!--Facebook Plugin-->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Does anybody know why it's not appearing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to paste this code

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://facebook.com/yourpage" data-width="The pixel width of the plugin" data-height="The pixel height of the plugin" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-send="false"></div>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Please have a look at this working

> [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ssfh5drL/1/)

Comment: I have that code in there and it's still not appearing, just to double check I pasted the code you provided and still nothing

Comment: are you working on your local machine or online? @cwattsdis

Comment: then this script only works online as far as I know..upload it to your web server and see, it should work

Comment: Uploaded it and it is there. Thank you!